# How to modify Jersey client code to do client certificate authentication?

Tags: java, jersey

We have some code that was written a while ago that acts as an SSL client but only does server-authenticated SSL:

```
protected String retrieveResponse(String request) throws IOException {
        Client client = setupConnection();
        WebResource fileResource = client.resource(this.config.getAREndpoint());
        return fileResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).type(MediaType.TEXT_XML).post(String.class, request);
    }
    
    protected Client setupConnection() throws IOException {
        try {
            // set up the client configuration & service
            Client client = new ClientBuilder(
                    new PropertyEncryptorDecryptor(Base64.decode(this.config.getFedConfig().getEncryptionKey())))
                        .createClient("TLSv1.2",
                            this.config.getConfig().getSSLClientKeyStoreFile(), 
                            this.config.getConfig().getSSLClientKeyStoreAlias(),
                            this.config.getConfig().getSSLClientKeyStorePassword(), 
                            this.config.getConfig().getSSLClientKeyStoreType(), 
                            this.config.getConfig().getSSLTrustStoreFile(), 
                            this.config.getConfig().getSSLTrustStorePassword(), 
                            this.config.getConfig().getSSLTrustStoreType());
            
            // to avoid messing with the common code, obtaining the properties and resetting
            // the hostname verifier
            HTTPSProperties properties = (HTTPSProperties) client.getProperties().get(HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES);
            HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            
            client.getProperties().put(HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES, new HTTPSProperties(hostnameVerifier, properties.getSSLContext()));
            client.setConnectTimeout(this.config.getFederationConnectTimeout().intValue());
            client.setReadTimeout(this.config.getFederationReadTimeout().intValue());
            return client;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String errorMessage = "Unable to initialize Jersey Client";
            logger.error(errorMessage);
            throw new RuntimeException(errorMessage, e);
        }
```

Now, I want to modify the above code so that it does client certificate authentication (i.e, where the client sends a client cert to the server and establish a 2-way SSL connection).

Can anyone tell me what I need to modify to do that?

Thanks,
Jim